# Difference between Run vs Run as in Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, ide

I'm new to Java hence the question that seems dumb.

When I was using CodeBlocks for C, there were two options: build and run.

But in eclipse, I see 3 three: build, run, run as. Both run and run as seems to do the same thing.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still pretty new to programming myself, so there's certainly more to it than I can tell you, but basically, "Run as" gives you a few more options than simply "Run".

Once you start building more complex applications that use dependency management services (like Maven) or frameworks (like Spring) there will be options to choose from when you click "Run as". Since you (presumably) don't have any of that yet, the buttons do the same for you.